# Subtle difference between "I insist he be punished" and "I insist he should be punished"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, mandative-subjunctive

> 1. I insist he **be** punished.

and

> 2. I insist he **should be** punished.

What's the ***SUBTLE*** difference between them?

Comment: There is no meaningful difference between the two of them. They both have a mandative interpretation. -- Syntactically, your #1 is a **subjunctive mandative** and your #2 is a ***should*-mandative**. (Aside: Sometimes in some non-mandative usages, there might not be a case of modal harmony between an "insist" and a "should".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are insisting on two different things.

In the first, you are insisting on an actual result: that someone is punished.

In the second, you are insisting on **your opinion** that someone should be punished.

Comment: Isn't it, more simply, a difference between British usage (that sb should do, a modal equivalent of the Present Simple Subjunctive) and American usage (that sb do, Present Simple Subjunctive)? WITHOUT ANY DIFFERENCE between the two structures?!

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain thing from my perspective.....hope it is fine.

Here we go......

I insist he be punished = I want the person should get punishment for the wrong / incorrect thing he has done....but I cannot catch him....so my basic emotional reaction is -----he should get the punishment.....here is an example.....

You are driving the car and going in regular manner to your office.
Suddenly, a car comes from your backside and overtakes you very fast....
You are unaware and struggle to control your car with cursing him.....
Here -----you want ***He be Punished***......you cannot do anything to him...
But your basic desire is that, he should get the punishment ....
so here in this case you will say ***He be Punished***

Now another case------I insist he should be punished
here in this case, you have proof of his wrong / incorrect things.....you have solid evidence of his misconduct / frauds / cheating etc., etc., 
so while telling this to your Boss / Police Commissioner/Jury......you will say 
***I insist he should be punished***

for example....you have created a great report and your enemy deleted all the work......you suffered a heavy loss.....you found out that person....
you told this to your boss.....gave all evidence......all proofs....and finally said....***I insist he should be punished***

here you have caught the man...you have the chance to get the things clear to him.....so  you will say...***I insist he should be punished***

hope now your doubt is cleared....all the best